# Comparing the elements of an arrayList with one another

Tags: java

I have an array list with four object elements in it and i need to compare these objects with each other. I need to avoid the similar object comparisons and doing a continue in case if both objects are same. I have tried the below code but it's avoiding the common object iterations. Can anyone suggest me a best way to compare the elements in the same Array list?

Code:

```
List<Student> studentInfo= new ArrayList<Student>();

 for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0 ; j < list.size(); j++)
                {


                    if(list.get(i).getstudentId().equals(list.get(j).getstudentId())) 
                    continue;

                    }

                }

            }
```

Comment: You do double compares. Just let `j` start from `i+1`.

Comment: Your code as posted does not do anything useful (presumably there';s more code after the continue)- what are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: Nick, i have some conditions that i need to check during the comparisons and if those satisfies then i will set those values to some object. Like as i said i wanted to avoid the comparisons between the similar objects..

Comment: Unless you want to code yourself - you can use CollectionUtils library check https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/CollectionUtils.html

Comment: I recommend implementing the Comparable interface. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html

Answer (score 3):

you need to avoid the case where i == j in which case your if will evaluate to true

```
if(i != j && list.get(i).getstudentId().equals(list.get(j).getstudentId())) 
  break;
```

if you want to know at the exit of the loop if you found a duplicate, you need an external variable to let you know (like boolean or perhaps an int that will show where the duplicate was found)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the bubble sort algorithm but instead of sort, you could use it for your needs.

A more elegant method to compare would be:

```
public class Student {

    private String id;

    /**
     * @return the id
     */
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    /**
     * @param id the id to set
     */
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }



    @Override
    public boolean equals (Object otherObject){
        if(!(otherObject instanceof Student)){
            return false;
        }
        if(((Student)otherObject).getId().equals(this.id)){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

In your class:

```
for(int i = 0; i< studentList.size(); i++){
    for(int j = i+1; j< studentList.size(); j++){
        if(studentList.get(i).equals(studentList.get(j))){
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```